# Get the objects value of the object in the json array

Tags: arrays, json, object

I really need help! How can I get the values from "sentiment" key in my json data? I am getting result [Object object] and I know that I am making a wrong entrance into this key because it is the object but dont have any idea what is the solution for it.. Could you help?

```
 data = { 
                 "happiness_position": 80,          
                 "sentiment": {"ANGER": 84.0, "DEPRESION": 26.0
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++){
                var obj = artists[i];

                if(obj.nane == uservalue){

                    document.getElementById("voc").innerHTML = obj.happiness_position;
                    document.getElementById("emo").innerHTML = obj.sentiment;

                }
            }
```

Comment: because sentiment is a JSON in your JSON then its a object u shuold print its fields not it. somthing like `document.getElementById("emo").innerHTML = obj.sentiment.ANGER` or convert it to strnig by `document.getElementById("emo").innerHTML = JSON.stringfy(obj.sentiment)`

Comment: I need to print two values for ANGER and DEPRESSION with JSON.stringfy it gives me again [object Object]

Comment: its static json or dynamic its structure  will change ? if it change its hard! but if its static you can easily do it :`document.getElementById("emo").innerHTML = obj.sentiment.ANGER + "  " + ocument.getElementById("emo").innerHTML = obj.sentiment.Depression`

Comment: the problem is that it will be changing not always I will get ANGER or DEPRESSION that's why I wanted to base on "sentiment"

Answer (score 0):

try for on sentiment do dynamycly got its key :

```
 data = { 
                     "happiness_position": 80,          
                     "sentiment": {"ANGER": 84.0, "DEPRESION": 26.0
            }

        for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++){
                var obj = artists[i];

                if(obj.nane == uservalue){

                    document.getElementById("voc").innerHTML = obj.happiness_position;
                    document.getElementById("emo").innerHTML = ""
                    for(var key in obj.sentiment)
                    {
                       document.getElementById("emo").innerHTML+= key + ":" + obj.sentiment[key] + "\n"
                    }


                }
            }
```